# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value exception

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I was trying to concatenate the date and month with the Year and I need to check with the each record to find the financial year. When I execute the query it shows (**The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**) error. Please help me to find the issue.

**Code**

```
   set @SiteFileVal1='04-01'
   set @SiteFileVal2='03-31'
   set @SiteFileYear='2013'

   SELECT bb.Amount
   FROM Budget bb
   JOIN Invoice i ON i.AccountId=bb.AccountId
   WHERE bb.AccountId=i.AccountId
   AND bb.Year=
   (SELECT CASE WHEN (i.Date >= convert(datetime,@SiteFileVal1+'-'+convert(varchar(200),DATEPART(yyyy,i.Date)))
                   AND i.Date < convert(datetime,@SiteFileVal2+'-'+convert(varchar(200), DATEADD(yyyy,1,DATEPART(yyyy,i.Date))))) THEN year(@SiteFileYear) ELSE DATEADD(yyyy,-1,DATEPART(yyyy,i.Date)) END)
```

Comment: Of course, I don't know the schemas of the tables involved, but I suspect this query, even after the year gets calculated correctly, may return you many duplicates. Besides, you are not returning `AccountId` – how will you now which `Amount` is related to what `AccountId`? If you elaborated on what exactly you are trying to do, adding to the question data samples and the schemas of the tables used, we might suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is incorrect:
    DATEADD(yyyy,-1,DATEPART(yyyy,i.Date))

`DATEADD` expects a date passed in, and you are only passing in the year of a date -- `DATEPART(yyyy, i.Date)`

Using your code, I did:

```
select DATEADD(yyyy,-1,DATEPART(yyyy,'1/8/2007'));
```

The result?  1904-07-01 00:00:00.000

When I add a month/day back in, this is what I get:

```
select DATEADD(yyyy,-1, CAST(DATEPART(mm, '1/8/2007') as varchar) + '/' + 
 CAST(DATEPART(DD, '1/8/2007') as varchar) + '/' + 
 cast(DATEPART(yyyy,'1/8/2007') as varchar))
```

result:  2006-01-08 00:00:00.000

This is a lot of parsing for a query, but here's what you need, formatted to your column.

```
set @SiteFileVal1='04-01'
set @SiteFileVal2='03-31'
set @SiteFileYear='2013'

SELECT bb.Amount
FROM Budget bb
JOIN Invoice i ON i.AccountId=bb.AccountId
 WHERE bb.AccountId=i.AccountId
  AND bb.Year=
DatePart(yyyy,
(CASE WHEN (i.Date >= convert(datetime,@SiteFileVal1+'-'+convert(varchar(200),DATEPART(yyyy,i.Date)))
               AND i.Date < convert(datetime,@SiteFileVal2+'-'+convert(varchar(200), DATEADD(yyyy,1,CAST(DATEPART(mm, i.Date) as varchar) + '/' +
      CAST(DATEPART(DD, i.Date) as varchar) + '/' + 
          cast(DATEPART(yyyy,i.Date) as varchar))))) 
          THEN year(@SiteFileYear) ELSE 
DATEADD(yyyy,-1, CAST(DATEPART(mm, i.Date) as varchar) + '/' +
      CAST(DATEPART(DD, i.Date) as varchar) + '/' + 
      cast(DATEPART(yyyy,i.Date) as varchar)) END) )
```

Comment: Still I am facing the same out of range value exception.

Comment: @Deva, there was a second spot in the query where the same issue was happening.  I've updated the final example for you.

Comment: Still I am facing the same issue even after including your updated query.

Comment: Try again.  The year was not being returned for bb.Year, the whole date was.